# Transfert an url with parameters into a pretty URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to use URL rewrite with my .htaccess to redirect my non pretty URL:

> `http://example.com/_new/url.php?module=planning&action=see&id=2`

to this one:

> `http://example.com/_new/url/planning/see/2`

So I used:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ url.php?module=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ url.php?module=$1&action=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ url.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [L]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this specific url rewrite, You might need to replace your [RewriteRule] to something like this:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
>   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
>
> RewriteRule ^_new/url/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ 
>   _new/url.php?module=$1&action=$2&id=$3 [NC,L]

From which you can access: http://example.com/_new/url.php?module=planning&action=see&id=2

> http://example.com/_new/url/{module_name} = http://example.com/_new/url.php?module={module_name}

The same applies for $2, $3 as well.

[NC] = Case insensitive : This flag tells apache that there will be [no case]

[L] = If this rule was already processed to begin with, No additional rules will be added in the current url rewriting process

You can learn more about here: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hello, I have this error: `The requested URL /_new/url/planning/see/2.php was not found on this server.`